# "in the noble gases" vs. "in noble gases" -- would it be okay to omit the definite article?

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

From [ChemGuide](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/structures/molecular.html):

> Molecules are made of fixed numbers of atoms joined together by covalent bonds, and can range from the very small (even down to single atoms, as **in the noble gases**) to the very large (as in polymers, proteins or even DNA).

Would it be okay to omit the definite article here:

> Molecules are made of fixed numbers of atoms joined together by covalent bonds, and can range from the very small (even down to single atoms, as **in noble gases**) to the very large (as in polymers, proteins or even DNA).

After all, the author refers to **noble gases** generically; he then refers to **proteins** and **polymers** generically. Or is it better to use **the** because *the noble gases* is a well-defined, well-known, small group of elements?

Comment: *"Or is it better to use 'the' because **the** noble gases is a well-defined, well-known, small group of elements?"*; yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

As a <s>chemist</s> someone who studies chemistry a lot, if I were to write that sentence, I would have used zero article.

We originally know what noble gases are, so yes; this would be a generic mention of them, and that's a [use case of zero article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-marking_in_English#Zero_article).

[This n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=noble+gases%2Cthe+noble+gases&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnoble%20gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnoble%20gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNoble%20gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNoble%20Gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNOBLE%20GASES%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthe%20noble%20gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20noble%20gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20noble%20gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20Noble%20Gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20Noble%20Gases%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTHE%20NOBLE%20GASES%3B%2Cc0) suggests that since there's a difference between the frequency of the token "noble gases (All)" and "the noble gases (All)", the zero article version certainly exists, if is not more common.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But what if the Ngram search result for "noble gases" includes all the instances of "the noble gases", since the first line is merely a part of the second? There could be some other combinations, like "a noble gases factory". (0:

Comment: Yes, Copper, it does. I'm not comparing the two diagrams. I'm comparing the first diagram and the difference between the two diagrams, which is more accurately any instances of "noble gases" that isn't "**the** noble gases" and that'd be "noble gases"; which has zero article.

Comment: @CopperKettle Well, it's certainly grammatical either way.  If the difference does matter in your example, it's very subtle.

Comment: @snailboat - thanks! Maybe the version with **the** is more "scientifically-looking". I recall that Quirk et al. wrote that some scientists use **the** almost generically, as in "*the rodents*" - to refer to the order Rodentia.

Comment: With respect, your n-gram is skewed by the fact that the term "noble gases" is contained in the term "the noble gases".  In order to get an accurate comparison, you would have to subtract the red-line values from the blue-line values.  Comparing "in the noble gases "with "in noble gases" avoids this problem.  If you do so, you will see that the former is more common in the 60's, they are about equal in the 80's, and the latter is more common in the 00's.  This suggests that the trend over time is to drop the article.

Comment: Yes @BobRodes. I do know that 'noble gases' contains 'the noble gases'. I wasn't trying to do a comparison between the commonness of the two. I was trying to prove that the zero article version exists. And by 'difference between the frequency of the token "noble gases (All)" and "the noble gases (All)"' I do mean the subtraction of the values.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ., Copperkettle MAR, your argument won't quite hold there, because *the X noble gases* will also be included in *noble gases* but not in *the noble gases*. Also other determiners might be being used too. So the other instances might be *some noble gases*, *these noble gases*, *a few noble gases*, *three noble gases*, *three of the noble gases*, *many noble gases* and so forth.

Comment: @Arau I'm close to flipping a table. **I do know that 'noble gases' contains 'the noble gases'** and this is the third time I'm saying it in the comments of this very thread. I was just implying that there's a good portion of "noble gases" that isn't "the noble gases" (Blue minus red values) and other dets are rarely used to make such phrases, hence zero article 'noble gases' exists.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Sorry, old bean, but you seem to be implying that maybe "noble gases" is more common. That's what I read from "if is not more common" in your last line. You also say that the NGram shows that bare *noble gases* certainly exists. But from the Ngram itself, nothing of the sort is shown. You understand that as a scientist, right? You might be able to see that if you actually leave the Ngram and go and look at the examples, but you can't see that from the Ngram. In other words a couple of quotes would be worth a thousand Ngrams here.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. In case it's not clear, what do you think an Ngram would look like for *donkey* versus *a donkey*? The *donkey* one would be bigger. But we shouldn't extrapolate from that that we can use bare NP *donkey* on its own. Right?

Comment: No @Arau, I'm trying to imply that such usage exists. But yeah, I agree, I should bring up examples . . . after I took a nap.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Ok, I understand what you were trying to do then.  My example is still a better way to do it.  LOL